# Disable jQuery scrollbar plugin on touch devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a jQuery scrollbar plugin (perfectScrollbar) to handle a couple of overflow:hidden divs on desktop viewport sizes.  The root of the problem is the scrollbar doesn't support passing the scroll (wheelPropogation) back to the parent on touch devices

In my CSS targeting smaller viewport sizes, I would've thought simply switching the div height and overflow to "auto" would've solved my problem since the div itself doesn't need to be scrollable on the smaller viewports.

The CSS piece works as all of the content within the div becomes visible on these smaller screens, but the plugin is still firing and is causing the user to get stuck once they've hit the div in question.  It's not passing the scroll to the parent even though the div is no longer be scrollable.

Any easy suggestions?  What would be the best way to only fire the plugin when there's no touch screen?  I'm hoping to avoid modernizr simply for this issue, but will go that route if nobody has a better suggestion.

Desktop CSS:

```
#tasting-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top:0; 
    padding-left:.25em;
    line-height:1em;
    background:rgba(00,00,00,.5);
    border-radius:8px;
    position:relative;
    height:23.5em;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Mobile CSS:

```
#tasting-menu{
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
// Plugins

  $('#tasting-menu').perfectScrollbar({
    includePadding: true,
    wheelPropagation: true
```

HTML:

```
<div id="#tasting-menu>
    <p>A bunch of content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add a class to the body for different viewport sizes and only use .perfectScrollbar on the classes you created for the larger sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to do some user agent detection before invoking perfectScrollbar

```
var is_mobile = ((/Mobile|Android|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i).test(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera) ? true : false);

if ( !is_mobile ) {
  $('#tasting-menu').perfectScrollbar({
    // ...
  });
}
```